# Iterative Method for Pricing American Put Option

Tags: python, algorithm, quantitative-finance

I am trying to implement an algorithm for pricing American option using the Iterative method as in the paper "A Simple Iterative Method for the Valuation of American Options"

The math might be complicated but we don't have to worry much about it. The basic idea is that we divide the time to maturity into n intervals (n+1 nodes), at each node, we have one optimal exercise boundary and we try to fit a curve that goes through all these points (n-degree polynomial). The name "iterative method" suggests that we conduct this approximation a few times, each time we have a better curve where it will be closer to the correct curve.

Enough said, with the follow parameters: S,T,K,n,,r,sigma,k; the algorithm is as below:

1. Divide time to maturity into n intervals, which creates n+1 exercise boundaries. t0, t1, t2,...ti,..,tn
2. At t=0 (maturity), the optimal exercise boundary is K (strike price).
3. Initial guess for B(ti) = K
4. Apply formula (6) to find the first round of estimation for B(i).

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MJEaQ.png)

5. Approximate polynomial function for n+1 data points of B(ti)

   Use equation (5) to go for the next round of iteration

   Keep repeating step 5. k times, or until convergence

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IrMXb.png)

Below is my codes for these 2 steps in Python:

```
dt=T/n
B = [K]*(n+1)
#first iteration - equation (6) in paper
for i in range(n):
    i+=1
    tt = i*dt
    A1 = K*(NCDF(d12(K,tt,K)[0])+(1/sig/np.sqrt(2*np.pi*tt))*np.exp(-0.5*d12(K,tt,K)[0]**2))**(-1)
    A2 = 1/sig/np.sqrt(2*np.pi*tt)*np.exp(-(r*tt+0.5*d12(K,tt,K)[1]**2))
    A3 = (2*sig*r)/(2*r+sig**2)*(2*NCDF((2*r+sig**2)*np.sqrt(tt)/(2*sig))-1)
    B[i]=A1*(A2+A3)

for i in range(k): #kth iteration as in equation (5)
    xvals=np.linspace(0,T,n+1)
    params=np.polyfit(xvals,B,deg=n)
    for j in range(n): #equation (5) at each node point
        j+=1
        tt = j*dt
        A1 = (NCDF(d12(B[j],tt,K)[0])+(1/sig/np.sqrt(2*np.pi*tt))*np.exp(-0.5*d12(B[j],tt,K)[0]**2))**(-1)
        A2 = (1/sig/np.sqrt(2*np.pi*tt)*K*np.exp(-(r*tt+0.5*d12(B[j],tt,K)[1]**2)))
        A3 = r*K*sci.fixed_quad(lambda x: (1/sig/np.sqrt(2*np.pi*(tt-x)))*r*np.exp(-(r*(tt-x)+\
        0.5*d12(B[j],tt,Polyf(params,x))[1]**2)),0,tt)[0]
        B[j]=A1*(A2+A3)

xvals=np.linspace(0,T,n+1)
params=np.polyfit(xvals,B,deg=n)

Price = BSPut(S0,K,r,sig,T) + sci.fixed_quad(lambda x: r*K*np.exp(-r*(T-x))*NCDF(-d12(S0,T-x,Polyf(params,x))[1]),0,T)[0]
return Price
```

Don't worry about the function Polyf and BSPut as I have checked them carefully. The issue is that I could never replicate the correct result with these codes. Even the curve of B(ti) after the first round of iteration doesn't match the result in the paper at S = 45, K = 45, r=0.05, sigma = 0.2, T = 0.5, n = 16. If you run my codes, the B1(ti) is much lower than the B1(ti) in the paper (I think the min value is approx 41 while my program gave me B(16) = 37 after first iteration.

[Example Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tOaFS.png)

I would really appreciate it if someone could show me what possibly goes wrong in my implementation.

Thanks so much!

Comment: If there was an example code that would run right out of the box while being as short as possible at the same time, it would make the question easier to answer. See also [example].

Comment: Hi, in the loop, you have `i+=1`, do you want it advance `i` by 1 or by 2?

Comment: Same potential issue in the second loop with `j += 1`, in python the `for j in range(n)` statement is the equivalent of `for (j=0; j<n; j++)` in C-like syntax.

Comment: Hi Trilarion, I am afraid no..sorry I should have put the top line as def IterativeMethod(S,K,r,sig,T,n,k)

Comment: Hi Phong, the reason I advance the index by 1 is because at maturity (t = 0), the optimal exercise boundary is always K so there is no need to do any calculation. Equation (5) and (6) only starts with the first time node. Python loop starts at 0

Comment: Hi m.raynal, the answer is similar to what I said to Phong, equations (5) and (6) doesn't start at t=0 as optimal exercise is always K at maturity so I advance the index by 1, it would give me the required t as in these (5) and (6) equations.